# Doubts with SDL_UpdateTexture

Tags: textures, sdl

I have seen in the wiki this entry for the function SDL_UpdateTexture:

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture

Later, it says this:

*This is a fairly slow function, intended for use with static textures.

This function will work with streaming textures, but for optimization reasons you may not get the pixels back if you lock the texture afterward.*

Wtf? I thought it was reverse. Static access for textures is meant to be a not-so-often update of the texture, and a streaming access for my texture is meant to write data a lot of times in it (to "update" its data very often)

Then is this wrong in the wiki? If not, what is the good function for a streaming access texture?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lighting engine that uses SDL_UpdateTexture to dump its light map onto the scene and in 2.0.3 there does not seem to be an appreciable difference in performance if you do it on a STATIC or a STREAMING

Regardless, it is indeed a very slow function. The slowness has to do with SDL having to ferry the pixel information from main memory to GPU memory... so it should be used sparingly. More than one big UpdateTexture per frame can begin to tax older hardware.